# Issue when loading angular components

Tags: angular

I am learning angular.

everything in the code works fine.

when I reload the page, i see the following errors in the console:

[image: error]
if i click on 'chrome-extension://invalid/' I see the following::
[image: error2]
If I click on 'inject.bundle.js:1
I see the following
[image: error3]

Any idea where these errors could be from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an issue with a chrome extension that you have. Try removing extensions until the error goes away.